# Find duplicates in comma-separated string data using R

Tags: r

I am currently trying to run multiple data using loop, and ended up with the results below. Each line corresponds to the output from one data that has been filtered.

I am using this code to get the results below.

```
 output <- print(paste(data.final$Peptide, collapse = ','))
```

It was previously given the form of table with one of the column name "Peptide", so I am pasting the peptide into a string separated comma, as shown here :

```
[1]"LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPSAYTNSF,SAYTNSFTR,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPSAYTNSF,SAYTNSFTR,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY"
[1]"LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,TSNQVAVLY"
```

I would like to find the number of duplicates from each comma-separated strings (eg. LPPAYTNSF) between the lines.

Is there anyways to do this?

Comment: This is not a complete question.  Your sample data needs to be included as _text_, directly in the question.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Firstly, please don't post code or data as images if it could be text, it is much harder for people to use your data to help you.  Secondly, please show us what you have already tried?  The site is not intended to be a replacement for reading the documentation and/or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you well, there is no reason to first collapse them to a string. Why not just get the counts from your data.frame? Any n > 1 has duplicates.

```
data.final %>% count(Peptide)
```

**solution based on your string**

```
table(unlist(strsplit(v, ",")))
```

**results**

```
ASFSTFKCY CVADYSVLY KIYSKHTPI LPFNDGVYF LPPAYTNSF LPSAYTNSF QSYGFQPTY RLFRKSNLK SANNCTFEY SAYTNSFTR TSNQVAVLY WMESEFRVY 
        8         8         8         8         6         2         6         8         8         2         8         8 
WTAGAAAYY YLQPRTFLL YNSASFSTF YSSANNCTF 
        8         8         8         8
```

**data**

```
v <- "LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,TSNQVAVLY,LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY,LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY,LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY,LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY,LPSAYTNSF,SAYTNSFTR,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY,LPSAYTNSF,SAYTNSFTR,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,QSYGFQPTY,TSNQVAVLY,LPPAYTNSF,LPFNDGVYF,WMESEFRVY,YSSANNCTF,SANNCTFEY,KIYSKHTPI,WTAGAAAYY,YLQPRTFLL,CVADYSVLY,YNSASFSTF,ASFSTFKCY,RLFRKSNLK,TSNQVAVLY"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what your data are like so I've scribbled together some toy data to show how a regex and a non-regex `tidyverse` solution would work on your task of "find[ing] the number of duplicates from each comma-separated strings":

Data:

```
x <- c("a,c,x,a,f,s,w,s,b,n,x,q",
       "A,B,B,X,B,Q")
```

A regex tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x) %>%
# create new column with duplicated values:
mutate(dups = str_extract_all(x, "([A-Za-z])+(?=.*\\1)"))
                        x    dups
1 a,c,x,a,f,s,w,s,b,n,x,q a, x, s
2             A,B,B,X,B,Q    B, B
```

**NB**: the `+` in the regex pattern makes sure you can use this solution also for longer-than-one-character alphabetic comma-separated strings

Alternatively, a non-regex tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(x) %>%
  # make column with unique ID for each string:
  mutate(stringID = row_number()) %>%
  # separate values into rows:
  separate_rows(x) %>%
  # for each combination of `stringID` and `x`...
  group_by(stringID, x) %>%
  # ...count the number of tokens:
  summarise(N = n()) %>%
  # show only the duplicated values:
  filter(N > 1)
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   stringID [2]
  stringID x         N
     <int> <chr> <int>
1        1 a         2
2        1 s         2
3        1 x         2
4        2 B         3
```